# Make Ubuntu look like Parrot os

Tags: themes

I've been trying to make Ubuntu look like Parrot OS. I found the github for the Parrot themes but I can't figure out how to use it on Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Comment: With a little more information (what type of files did you download from the github etc) might have allowed a more helpful response.  If you have correct themes files (or directories), you can put a copy in your `~./themes/` directory (ie. .themes directory in your user folder), or if you want them used by all users, put a copy in `/usr/share/themes/`.   You then change your theme to whatever theme you added in the normal way (the list of themes should detect the new files/folder of files in either location; if it doesn't it may mean its for a different DEsktop)

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry I didn't include that in the first place.  I'm not used to using themes i normally use the Unity-esque theme, I'm just going to link to the GitHub page where i got it.  I tried doing what you said but nothing. I've used        the default desktop that Ubuntu comes with and MATE but to no avail.                     https://github.com/ParrotSec/parrot-themes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parrot-themes GitHub repository has Debian [control file](https://github.com/ParrotSec/parrot-themes/blob/master/debian/control#L1) to produce deb-package. The package will be named `parrot-themes`.

There is no need to build it by yourself, you can download it from ParrotOS repository and install manually:

```
wget http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot/pool/main/p/parrot-themes/parrot-themes_2.6+parrot6_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./parrot-themes_2.6+parrot6_all.deb
```

Then open *System -> Preferences -> Look and Feel -> Appearance* (or `mate-appearance-properties`) and select Parrot OS theme (one of *air*, *ARK-Dark*, *ARK-Light*, *ARK-Snow*, *Icy-Dark*, *Icy-Light*).

And you will get your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE styled as Parrot OS (*air* theme as example):

[image: air theme from Parrot OS on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE]